# How can you create a transaction/batch write between multiple Firestore instances?

Tags: firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Firebase allows having [multiple projects in a single application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#support_multiple_environments_in_your_android_application).

```
// Initialize another app with a different config
var secondary = firebase.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, "secondary");

// Retrieve the database.
var secondaryDatabase = secondary.database();
```

**Example**: 
Project 1 has my users collection; Project 2 has my friends collection (suppose there's a reason for that). When I add a new friend in the Project 2 database, I want to increment the friendsCount in the user document in Project 1. For this reason, I want to create a transaction/batch write to insure consistency in the data.

How can I achieve this? Can I create a transaction or a batch write between different Firestore instances?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use the database transaction feature across multiple databases.

If absolutely required, I'd probably instead create a custom locking feature. From wiki,

> To allow several users to edit a database table at the same time and also prevent inconsistencies created by unrestricted access, a single record can be locked when retrieved for editing or updating. Anyone attempting to retrieve the same record for editing is denied write access because of the lock (although, depending on the implementation, they may be able to view the record without editing it). Once the record is saved or edits are canceled, the lock is released. Records can never be saved so as to overwrite other changes, preserving data integrity.
>
> In database management theory, locking is used to implement isolation among multiple database users. This is the "I" in the acronym ACID.
>
> Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_locking

Comment: can you add a link to the source of the quote?

Answer (score 0):

It's been three years since the question, I know, but since I needed the same thing I found a working solution to perform the double (or even ^n) transaction. You have to nest the transactions like this.

```
db1.runTransaction(t1 => db2.runTransaction(t2 => async () => {
   await t1.set(.....
   await t2.update(.....
   etc....
})).then(...).catch(...)
```

Since the error is propagated in the nested promises it is safe to execute the double transaction in this way because for a failure in any one of the databases it results in the error in all of them.